# Parse.com recursive save and performance / requests per second

Tags: ios, performance, parse-platform

I have a parse "parent" object that has many (1,500) related "child" objects stored in an array.

**EDIT** OK, reading the docs it shouldn't be an array type relation but should be a pointer relation from the child back to the parent. However, that would make my situation worse as then I'd have to create thousands of requests from the device to save each child in turn. Which would put me back in the situation I'm in now of not being able to store the data I want to store.

These are all created on the device and then I run this code to save the parent and children.

```
parentObject.saveInBackground().continue...
```

This recursively saves the parent object and all the child objects.

However, I then instantly received this email.

> Hi there,
>
> Your app [App Name] recently exceeded 75% of your plan's request limit of
>   30 requests/second. Additional requests to Parse exceeding the rate of
>   30 requests/second will be dropped, returning an error with error code
>   155.
>
> Take a look at your app's Performance graph and consider increasing
>   your plan's limit.
>
> Cheers, Team Parse

Am I to gather from this that a single save operation to save multiple objects will count as the multiple requests (one for each object)?

I followed their advice and looked at the performance graph...

[image]

As you can see, nothing even registers on there.

From my past experience we wouldn't even be hitting 0.1 requests per second at the moment.

If they are taking a recursive save as multiple requests then why is it not showing on the graph? If it's not showing on the graph then why the email?

Very confusing.

I guess the main question is this... How is the best way to use Parse to store potentially thousands of items at a time? They are all created at the same time and uploaded at the same time.

Maybe Parse isn't the right tool for this in the first place.

Comment: yes, each is a separate request (a single batch is counted by the number of items in the batch) - the batch only saves network traffic. maybe parse isn't right for you. you'd certainly need to up your account limits if you're routinely doing 1500 things at the same time

Comment: @Wain thanks. That's the conclusion I was coming to... unfortunately. 1500 is a small sample compared to the data that will be captured in production. Oh well, Parse is good for a lot of things... but not for this I guess :D

Comment: You're hitting the free account limit. If your app is routinely saving 1,500 objects at a time, you can simply bump the request limiter to something higher to account for the load your app requires.

Comment: @HectorRamos it was more a question of why I was hitting limit with only one save request. The thing is, this is a brand new app still in development with only me using it. Putting up the limit isn't going to help with multiple users. Decided to drop parse.com in the end. Going to do our own back end.

Comment: Hi Fog, BTW you're right that this would not be an array (indeed I'd say as a rule, largely just forget about and don't use the "array" feature, which is something of a silly feature in Parse).  I was wondering if you're saving 1500 things once only (ie, at development time) or do you mean that users will commonly be saving 1500 things.

Comment: @JoeBlow in production we expect users to be saving in excess of 10,000 children per parent. They are very light weight items though (geopoint and timestamp). As you can probably guess it's a fitness activity tracker type app. We will no doubt have to batch the upload up no matter what system we user but if we had 100 users all trying to save 10,000 items at the same time that would take a considerable amount of time and no doubt drop a lot of the data due to request limit.

Comment: Hi Fog. Right - That is not suitable for Parse.  But note.  Even if just using a session connected to a database, would you really save each item (each "fitness point") as a separate item?  Personally I'd just save that record of 10,000 (say) as simply one text file (just one blob or whatever in a db). A simple example is: with every GPS app out there, when you go running 20km that is saved as a GPS data file, with for 20km some 3 or 4 thousand points (every few meters).  But note, **you don't really save each 'point' as an actual DB entry**. You just save "that run" ...

Comment: .. you save that overall run as a text blob (perhaps in xml format - whatever). It's then likely that each 'run" would be one item in your database.  So I'm wondering if you **truly need to save 10,000 'actual database lines'** for each user or each event?  There are very, very few situations where a user's "anything" has 10,000 items.